# How to add boost library 1_65 or 1_64 to Visual Studio 2017 project?

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to add boost 1_64 (boost 1_65 will also work) to my Visual Studio 2017 project which includes boost/array.hpp and boost/asio.hpp and used various methods of the same.

I have used the following method https://studiofreya.com/2017/04/23/building-boost-1-64-with-visual-studio-2017/  but I am getting error: cannot open source file "boost/array.hpp" and cannot open source file "boost/asio.hpp" and other errors on the methods of boost.

Answer (score 9):

The error implies that you haven't added `boost` to the `VC++ Directories`.
To add them:

- Open the `Property Manager` from the `View` -> `Other Windows` menu.
- Click on the project and navigate down to `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user`.
- Right click and select `Properties`.
- Open `Common Properties` and select `VC++ Directories`
- Add the directory where you installed `boost` to `Include Directories`
- Add the directory where you built`boost` libraries to `Library Directories`

Also see [Boost Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) in case you get stuck elsewhere.